# Playing Mp3 file using FFmpeg on Android

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This question has been asked a lot but no code has worked for me . i've been able to play a file decoded with ffmpeg on Android but it's noisy and glitchy.
i've found code in book called "linux sound programming" using latest ffmpeg version to decode an mp3 file.
the code tries to decode an mp3 file to pcm and then put it in a file called output.
what i want to do is to get the byte decoded on the fly and send them to AudioTrack in Java.

```
 void JNICALL Java_com_example_home_hellondk_MainActivity_loadFile
        (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,jstring file,jbyteArray array)
{

 jboolean isfilenameCopy;
         const char * filename = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, file,
                 &isfilenameCopy);
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
         jmethodID play = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "playSound", "([BI)V");
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int len;
    FILE *f, *outfile;
    uint8_t inbuf[AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
    AVPacket avpkt;
    AVFrame *decoded_frame = NULL;
AVFormatContext* container=NULL;
    av_init_packet(&avpkt);
 int num_streams = 0;
    int sample_size = 0;
    printf("Decode audio file %s \n", filename);
LOGE("Decode audio file %s\n", filename);
    /* find the MPEG audio decoder */
  /*  codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP3);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        LOGE("Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }*/
int lError;
         if ((lError = avformat_open_input(&container, filename, NULL, NULL))
                 != 0) {
             LOGE("Error open source file: %d", lError);
             exit(1);
         }
         if ((lError =  avformat_find_stream_info(container,NULL)) < 0) {
             LOGE("Error find stream information: %d", lError);
             exit(1);
         }
         LOGE("Stage 1.5");
        LOGE("audio format: %s", container->iformat->name);
       LOGE("audio bitrate: %llu", container->bit_rate);

    int stream_id = -1;
        // To find the first audio stream. This process may not be necessary
        // if you can gurarantee that the container contains only the desired
        // audio stream
           LOGE("nb_streams: %d", container->nb_streams);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < container->nb_streams; i++) {
            if (container->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                stream_id = i;
                 LOGE("stream_id: %d", stream_id);
                break;
            }
        }

        AVCodecContext* codec_context = container->streams[stream_id]->codec;
        codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_context->codec_id);
         LOGE("stream_id: %d", stream_id);
        LOGE("codec %s", codec->name);
        if (!codec) {
            fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio codec context\n");
          LOGE("Could not allocate audio codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
         LOGE("Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        LOGE("Could not open %s\n",filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    const char *outfilename;
 outfile = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
    if (!outfile) {
        av_free(c);
        exit(1);
    }


        avpkt.data = inbuf;
        avpkt.size = fread(inbuf, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE, f);
        LOGE("Stage 5");
    /* decode until eof */

     while (avpkt.size > 0) {
           int got_frame = 0;
           if (!decoded_frame) {
               if (!(decoded_frame = av_frame_alloc())) {
                   fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
                   exit(1);
               }
               } else {
                           av_frame_unref(decoded_frame);
                       }
                       printf("Stream idx %d\n", avpkt.stream_index);
                       len = avcodec_decode_audio4(c, decoded_frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);
                       if (len < 0) {
                           fprintf(stderr, "Error while decoding\n");
                           exit(1);
                       }
                       if (got_frame) {
                           printf("Decoded frame nb_samples %d, format %d\n",
                                  decoded_frame->nb_samples,
                                  decoded_frame->format);
                           if (decoded_frame->data[1] != NULL)
                               printf("Data[1] not null\n");
                           else
                               printf("Data[1] is null\n");
                           /* if a frame has been decoded, output it */
                           int data_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, c->channels,
                                                                      decoded_frame->nb_samples,
                                                                      c->sample_fmt, 1);
                           // first time: count the number of  planar streams
                           if (num_streams == 0) {
                               while (num_streams < AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS &&
                                      decoded_frame->data[num_streams] != NULL)
                                   num_streams++;
                               printf("Number of streams %d\n", num_streams);
                           }
                           // first time: set sample_size from 0 to e.g 2 for 16-bit data
                           if (sample_size == 0) {
                               sample_size =
                                   data_size / (num_streams * decoded_frame->nb_samples);
                           }
                           int m, n;

                           for (n = 0; n < decoded_frame->nb_samples; n++) {
                               // interleave the samples from the planar streams
                               for (m = 0; m < num_streams; m++) {
                                  fwrite(&decoded_frame->data[m][n*sample_size],
                                          1, sample_size, outfile);

                               }
                           }

                /*            jbyte *bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
                            memcpy(bytes, decoded_frame->data[1], data_size);
                            (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, bytes, 0);
                           (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, play, array, data_size);

*/
                       }
                       avpkt.size -= len;
                       avpkt.data += len;
                       if (avpkt.size < AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH) {
                           /* Refill the input buffer, to avoid trying to decode
                            * incomplete frames. Instead of this, one could also use
                            * a parser, or use a proper container format through
                              * libavformat. */
                                        memmove(inbuf, avpkt.data, avpkt.size);
                                        avpkt.data = inbuf;
                                        len = fread(avpkt.data + avpkt.size, 1,
                                                    AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE - avpkt.size, f);
                                        if (len > 0)
                                            avpkt.size += len;
                                    }
                                }

    fclose(f);

    avcodec_free_context(&c);
av_frame_free(&decoded_frame);

}
```

the decoded bytes are in this section
                 `fwrite(&decoded_frame->data[m][n*sample_size],                                           1, sample_size, outfile);`

the code that let you send bytes to java is this :

```
  jbyte *bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
  memcpy(bytes, decoded_frame->data[0], data_size);
 (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, bytes, 0);
 (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, play, array, data_size);
```

i've been working on it now for more than a week and nothing worked for me.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: why do you need `ffmpeg` for that?

Comment: Thank you pskink for your reply. i want to understand how the decoding and sending bytes to android because i want to create my own libary to handle any kind of file or stream audio . and for now i'm blocked in this simple test example for more than week now !

Comment: then use [exoplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) or low level `MediaCodec` / `MediaExtractor` stuff

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about Exoplayer , but it does not fit my need like creating buffer to rewind played stream.do you have any idea how to deal with it , the problem of ffmpeg and android is the poor documentation around ! it's not easy to handle it !

Comment: buffer? what buffer? see http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#pros-and-cons, `"The ability to customize and extend the player to suit your use case. ExoPlayer is designed specifically with this in mind, and allows many components to be replaced with custom implementations."`, see also **"Library overview"** section on the same page

Comment: I wanted to say that can i get the byte read by their library if i want to save for example ? can i only handle audio streams , i don't need video so the apk size may get bigger ? Thank you anyway i will take a look to it . but still wanna know how ffmpeg works with android if you know please help me at least for educational purpose. thanks

Comment: you have out-of-the-box, ready to use Exoplayer library, if you dont want to use it (i have no idea why), good luck with `ffmpeg` then

Comment: No  i will give a try ! but still want to understand how ffmpeg works.any way thanks so much for the suggestion.